# Unity: How to create a object on which can't teleport other object

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, unity3d-2dtools

how to create a 2D object on which can't teleport other (only stay on same position) object or can teleport only on one side (in picture left side). I have difficult and wrong way. Sorry for my English. There is project:

[link 3](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C7A243435ECAB1C0!3700&authkey=!ANeHTI_sCjXQVew&ithint=file%2czip)

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2Cst.png)

Comment: **can teleport only on one side**...Can you explain that well?Kudos for the picture but it doesn't help either.

Comment: I move with blue object and i want move blue to inside red object only from the left side. For example: Blue object position is like on picture, so blue object can't move/teleport down.

Comment: Do you understand? :)

Comment: @Yes I do. I am making an answer with images for you.

Comment: @Programmer Thank you very much :)

Comment: Take a look at my answer. Hopefully that's what you are looking for....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With fixed steps movement ("jumping") you need code logic to determine if a certain movement is possible. I suggest creating a class for the target (red object) that has a variable that states which side is open and a function to see if you can enter from the side you are on.
In your movement you need to check if such an object is in the direction you want to move to and ask it if you can enter from the side you are on.

This is pretty pseudo since I don't know your grid implementation and how you determine where stuff is and can probably be optimized.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if("move to left" && "object on left".GetComponent<RedObject>().canEnterFromSide("right") == true)
        {
            //move
        }
        else if("move to right" && "object on right".GetComponent<RedObject>().canEnterFromSide("left") == true)
        {
            //move
        }
        else if("move to top" && "object on top".GetComponent<RedObject>().canEnterFromSide("bottom") == true)
        {
            //move
        }
        else if("move to bottom" && "object on bottom".GetComponent<RedObject>().canEnterFromSide("top") == true)
        {
            //move
        }            
    }
}
```

And place a script on the object (or add this to its script if it has one already) with something like this.

```
public class RedObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    // use e.g. "left", "right", "top", "bottom" to specify the open side
    // if you spawn the objects, set this upon spawning and according to the orientation obviously
    public string openSide = "left";

    public bool canEnterFromSide(string side)
    {
        return side == openSide;
    }
}
```

**Update:**
Ok, I had a look into your project. Currently you don't have the part where you place the obstacles yet. This should be you next step.

Create a generator that will spawn your obstacles a positions on your grid (the grid intervals would be your player speed. Have a list or dictionary that holds a reference to all your placed obstacles so you can refer to them. An easy way would be something like this:

```
public class Generator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject obstaclePrefab;

    Dictionary<string, GameObject> obstacles;    // Dictionary requires using System.Collections.Generic;

    // default rotation = open to the left
    Dictionary<string, Quaternion> rotations;

    void Start()
    {
        rotations = new Dictionary<string, Quaternion>()
        {
            { "left", Quaternion.Euler(0,0,0) },
            { "bottom", Quaternion.Euler(0,90,0) },
            { "right", Quaternion.Euler(0,180,0) },
            { "top", Quaternion.Euler(0,270,0) }
        }
    }

    void SpawnObstacle(Vector2 position, string openSide)
    {
        GameObject go = (GameObject)Instantiate(obstaclePrefab, position, rotations[openSide]);
        go.GetComponent<Obstacle>().openSide = openSide;
        string pos = position.x + "_" + position.y;
        obstacles.Add(pos, go);
    }

    GameObject GetObjectAt(Vector3 position)
    {
        string pos = position.x + "_" + position.y;
        if(obstacles.ContainsKey(pos) == true)
        {
            return obstacles[pos];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now if you move, ask this class if there is an obstacle at the desired destination. (I left out the other stuff from this class.)

public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int step;

```
Generator generator;

void Start()
{
    generator = GameObject.FindWithTag("Generator");
}

void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        GameObject go = generator.GetObjectAt(transform.position - new Vector3(step, 0, 0));
        if(go == null || go.GetComponent<Obstacle>().CanEnterFromSide("right") == true)
        {
            transform.position = transform.position - new Vector3(step, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    // repeat for the other three directions.
}
```

}

Now, this uses a fixed chess like grid where an obstacle occupies one cell. Your video shows some other behaviour, so this will probably not quite help you. It Easiest would probably be to either make the player move in a smooth motion and use colliders and rigidbodys like Programmer showed or to use a fixed grid like this would be.

Comment: I'll look into it and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Can i send you my project?

Comment: Add it to your question.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I'll do it tomorrow, so I'll write tommorow. :)

Comment: can you send me back modified project? I've done something wrong.

Comment: I haven't modified anything because you probably have to change quite a bit of the surround stuff to get this to work so just load it from your question link.

Comment: `go.GetComponent<Obstacle>().openSide = openSide;`
I havent openSide, so i need create this, right?

Comment: Yes. Add the stuff I have in the second code snippet (RedObject) to your Obstacle.cs.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What is e.g. in _// use **e.g.** "left", "right", "top", "bottom" to specify the open side_ ? :)

Comment: E.g. stands for "for example".

Comment: I edited my project and upload back (second link in question) and i have bug with null reference. Can you help me? What does it mean `string pos = position.x + "_" + position.y;`? Thank you very very much, I am little idiot.

Comment: I made the Dictionary to have a key that has the position as string (could be Vector2 also) of scheme "X_Y" and values of type gameobject so you have a look-up for where those obstacles are. I actually forgot to initialize the obstacles dictionary in Start with `obstacles = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();`. I don't know if this is actually helping you because this way every obstacle would occupy on cell in the grid and the player could only move from cell to cell (like a chess board).

Comment: thanks, but when blue player is in red object with left open side and i press left arrow key, red stiil move with blue.
        `if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            GameObject go = generator.GetObjectAt(transform.position - new Vector3(speed, 0, 0));
            if (go == null || go.GetComponent<Obstacle>().canEnterFromSide("left"))
            {
                pos.x -= speed;
            }
        }`

Comment: The red object moves?

Comment: Can you edit your whole input part into your question? I didn't told the red object to move with my code above.

Comment: I solved my bugs with red object, but now blue player can go inside from all sides, so can i use onTriggerEnter/Stay/Exit in PlayerMove script? Is it the best way? They use three kids-object in red object. I upload new file in my question. Thanks :)

Comment: Where i can use SpawnObstacle?